# Use a linear approximation (or differentials) to estimate the given number.

Tags: calculus

Use linear approximation (or differentials) to estimate:

$$\sqrt {99.2}$$

What am I supposed to do with this? I am not given $x$ or $dx$.

Comment: Put braces {} around 99.2, so that the sqrt symbol knows the overline should cover the entire thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ue Taylor series for $\sqrt{x}$ about $x = 100$. The reason to expand the Taylor series about $100$ is that $100$ is the closest square to $99.2$.
$$f(x) = f(100) + f'(100) (x-100) + \text{higher order terms}$$
Hence,
$$\sqrt{99.2} \approx \sqrt{100} + \dfrac12 \dfrac{(99.2-100)}{\sqrt{100}} = 10 - \dfrac12 \dfrac{0.8}{10} = 10 - 0.04 = 9.96$$

Comment: @Henning Thanks for the fix.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! It makes sense now!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Is there any number near $99.2$ whose square root is *easy*?  That will be your $x$ value.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that $f'(a) \approx \tfrac{{f(x) - f(a)}}{{x - a}}$
so
$$f(x) \approx f(a) + f'(a)(x - a).$$
Now define $f(x) = \sqrt x $ and use the fact that $99.2 \approx 100$. We seek $f(100)$, so find $f'(x)$, 100 - 99.2, etc. You can also use differentials which is exactly the same since $f(x) - f(a) \approx dy$ and $x - a \approx dx$.